# Reusing Modified Three.js Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using Three.js to display the line of a particle following a random walk. Since geometries cannot be enlarged dynamically, I'm removing the line from the scene, altering the geometry and adding a new line to the scene. Here's the relevant code:

```
var step = .5;

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0077ff }); 
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0) );
scene.add( new THREE.Line( geometry, material ) );

var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( render ); 
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
}

function addStep() {
  scene.remove( scene.children[1] );
  last = geometry.vertices[ geometry.vertices.length - 1 ];
  geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( last.x + (2*Math.random()-1)*step,
        last.y + (2*Math.random()-1)*step, last.z + (2*Math.random()-1)*step ));
  scene.add( new THREE.Line( geometry.clone(), material ) );
}

setInterval( addStep, 500);
render();
```

This codes works, but only if the geometry is cloned at each step. If the last line of `addStep()` is changed to

```
  scene.add( new THREE.Line( geometry, material ) );
```

then it can be called as many times as desired before rendering starts to add line segments, but if called after rendering starts then nothing appears.

Presumably I'm missing something simple about graphics buffers or variable assignments, but I would appreciate if someone could explain why the modified geometry cannot be reused without cloning.

Comment: See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates for some tips. There should be no reason to remove your geometry from the scene.

Comment: @WestLangley I understand that I can construct a line with a given number of points and display them one by one, but that means a fixed number of steps. For an open-ended number I need to recreate the line, and the question is why can't the geometry simply be reused without cloning.

Answer (score 0):

@PaulMasson Here is a jsFiddle with an adaptation of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/theo/u6y4n67q/

```
function addStep() {

    vertices = geometry.vertices;
    last = vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ];
    vertices.push( 

        new THREE.Vector3( 
        last.x + ( 2 * Math.random() - 1 ) * step,
        last.y + ( 2 * Math.random() - 1 ) * step, 
        last.z + ( 2 * Math.random() - 1 ) * step ) 

    );

    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices = vertices;

    scene.remove( line );
    line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material )
    scene.add( line );

}
```

The only real difference is that this snippet uses `new THREE.Geometry()` instead of clone.

My guess is that Three.js geometry is tightly associated with with its representation in buffer geometry. Thus the only way to edit the geometry is to clone it or new it.